# Immutable data structure for a file that doesn't fit in memory

Tags: scala, io, immutability, scala-collections

Suppose I am reading a large file that does not fit in memory.
I can use an `Iterator` but iterators are mutable and I'd like to use an immutable data structure to model a file. `Stream`/`LazyList` are immutable but I cannot use them since they cache all their data in the memory.

Is there any *immutable* data structure for a large file that does not fit in memory ?

Comment: It depends on what do you really mean with _immutable_. Because, at the end, when the program is running it will be mutating to be loading more data from disk. So, immutable in this case is more about the abstraction it provides, so if you forget about `next()` and friends, then an **Iterator** is effectively _immutable_, but not reusable, but you may create a **view** from it and you would be good. Anyways, as I recommended you before, take a look into `fs2`.

Comment: How can I create a view from an iterator ?

Comment: oh it seems you can't, my bad. So yeah you can't reuse an **Iterator** that easily, you would need to call `duplicate`. In any case, you didn't answer the question, what do you mean with immutable in this case? And why you can't use something like `fs2`?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez `fs2` is a great tool indeed, but I think it would be fair to suggest to take a look in general at streaming solutions, not only `fs2` in particular, like `akka-stream` depending which stack is already used or desired to be used in project. Thanks

Comment: @IvanKurchenko I already recommended it to Michael in another answer. In this case I just mentioned it because it seems is the one which makes more sense for OP given his concerns about immutability.

Comment: Memoization (caching) only happens if something holds on to the head of the `Stream`/`LazyList`. The [Scaladocs page](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/LazyList.html) goes into some detail about this.

Comment: @jwvh Thanks. Do you know if it's safe to create a `LazyList` from an iterator of a very large file that does not fit in memory ?

Comment: It's safe if nothing holds on to the head, which might be tricky depending on what you're trying to do with the file content.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. I should try it.